# Pacman (Archlinux) Can'f find a package while it's present on AUR

Tags: stm32cubeide, arch, pacman-package-manager

I'm starting a new project with this new college year (embedded systems), and I've to use a switch from Microchip tools to STM tools. I'm using a STM32 Nucleo, so I need stm32cubeIDE to program it.
Here is my issue, when I try to install it on my arch disto :
`sudo pacman -S stm32cubeide`
I've an error :

> error : target not found : stm32cubeide

but if I check on [aur.archlinux.org](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/stm32cubeide), I can see the package is actually present.

I don't think my computer is the issue, as other packages (Tried with spotify) can be installed easily. What can I do about it ?
It's not a critical issue, as I can work on Windows. But my Windows PC don't have all "coding comfort" I've on my Arch PC (All my USB, RJ45, a qwerty keyboard...)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> "I don't think my computer is the issue."

No it doesn't have an issue. You can fetch normal packages with `sudo pacman -S package_name`. The problem you encounter is a different one. These packages are in the AUR (Arch user repository). They can't be downloaded with `pacman` because they are contributions by arch linux users. (Note: They might contain malicious code).

The `Arch User Repository` is community-driven. It contains [`PKGBUILDs`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PKGBUILD) that allow you to compile a package from source with [makepkg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Makepkg) and afterwards install it via *pacman*.

These are the general steps to properly install it (from the AUR manual page):

> 1. Acquire the build files, including the PKGBUILD and possibly other required files, like systemd units and patches (often not the actual
>    code).
> 2. Verify that the PKGBUILD and accompanying files are not malicious or untrustworthy.
> 3. Run makepkg in the directory where the files are saved. This will download the code, compile it, and package it.
> 4. Run pacman -U package_file to install the package onto your system.

What you really want is to have an [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AUR_helpers) that automatically downloads these packages for you. [Yay](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/yay) and [aura](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/aura) are common ones. In most cases you can also just directly install the packages from source on github and build it yourself with the build instructions, but generally a AUR helper is a good choice if you want to use AUR packages more often. If you want to get started with this, read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_User_Repository) document or refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbnSoY_yDr8) youtube video as a great starting point.

## In short, here are instructions to set up yay:

1. First you have to fetch the yay repository, which can be done like this:

   git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
2. After that just *cd* into the folder and look closely at the PKGBUILD-file and look if it has been corrupted. If there are some suspicious intructions like `rm -rf /` or something similar you can run in trouble when you run that command. So practise caution!
3. Then run the standard *make-package* command: `makepkg -si` or `makepkg --syncdeps`.

Now yay is successfully installed. You can use it similar to *pacman*. Just check the man-page for detailed info.

To install the package you require, do this:

```
yay -S stm32cubeide
```

Note: You don't have to put `sudo` before you execute a yay-command. It explicitly tells you if it needs *sudo* access privileges.